# TRying to show the following collection is a sigma algebra

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f: \Omega \to E $ be a function and let $\mathscr{E}$ be a sigma algebra of subsets of $E$. Let

$$ \mathscr{A} = \{ A \subset \Omega : \; \text{there exists} \; B \in \mathscr{E} \; \text{with} \; A = f^{-1}(B) \} $$

Then, $\mathscr{A}$ is a sigma algebra of subsets of $\Omega$.

$$Attempt$$

Since $f^{-1}( \varnothing) = \varnothing $ and $f^{-1}(E) = \Omega $, we have that $\varnothing, \Omega \in \mathscr{A}$. Next, suppose $f^{-1}(B_n) = A_n$ for all $n$ where $A_n \in \mathscr{A} $. From the identity

$$ \bigcup_n f^{-1}(B_n) = f^{-1}( \bigcup_n B_n ) $$

It follows that $\bigcup_n A_n \in \mathscr{A} $ since $\bigcup_n B_n \in \mathscr{E} $.

Hence, $\mathscr{A}$ is a sigma-algebra.

Is this a correct solution?

Added: Suppose $A \in \mathscr{A}$ so we can find $B \in \mathscr{E}$ such that $A = f^{-1}(B)$. Since $A^c = [f^{-1}(B)]^c = f^{-1}(B^c) $ and $B^c \in \mathscr{E}$, we have that $A^c \in \mathscr{A}$.

Comment: It is incomplete. You have not verified closure under complements.

Comment: You've forgot to check the case that if $A$ is in the sigma algebra then also $A^c$ is in it

Comment: @Andres Caicedo: I have updated my question. Does it look better now?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$